# Getting the root url in Django

Tags: django, django-urls

In my view, I want to make a request to `mine.com/more/stuff/` from an arbitrary page such as `mine.com/lots/of/stuff/to/use` or from `mine.com`.  Thus, I can't make this a relative request using `./` or `./../` type things.  Do I have to use a context processor to do `{{URL_BASE}}more/stuff/`?  Is there a set way to do this in Django or a best way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of a relative url, use an absolute url: `/`

If you're on `mine.com/lots/of/stuff/to/use` or `mine.com`, hitting a link with url: `/foo/` will both go to `mine.com/foo/`

Answer (score 8):

why don't you use named urls? it's always works.
for example `{% url 'admin:index' %}` always printed as url to admin(in case if you using default django.contrib.admin app).
if you'll have in urls.py smth like

```
url(r'^lots/', Lots.as_view(), name='lots'),
```

then just use smth like

```
{% url 'lots' %}
```

Don't hardcode your urls!

Comment: this would work also.  I will use this way when I build my next app.